# question on Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation

I have to find the Fourier Sine transform of $f(x)=1$ when $|x|<a$ and $f(x)=0$ when $|x|\ge a$
 and hence show that 
$$\int_0^\infty {\sin(t)\over t} dt =\pi/2$$
and 
$$\int_0^\infty \left({\sin(t)\over t}\right)^2 dt =\pi/2$$

I found the first two parts. 
How shall I proceed in order to prove the last part? 
please help.

Comment: Convolution, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that the Fourier transform is an $L^2$ isometry, i.e.

$$\langle \mathcal{F}f,\mathcal{F}f\rangle = \langle f,f\rangle,$$

where in your case $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |x|\le 1 \\ 0 & |x|>1\end{cases}.$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: He means Parseval's theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat good catch.

Comment: @Grazel what do you not understand?

Comment: @CameronWilliams- I'm not so much familiar with Parseval's theorem yet. So I'm trying to understand how to set the things so I get the answer.